# Google Sheets API stops working after 2 days

Tags: php, google-sheets

I'm configuring an application that have a cron, which is reading Google Sheets through the API. The proccess properly works 1st and 2nd day, but not 3rd.

When I run it the 1st day, it request me the validation code and works.
2nd day it works automatically (the validation code is not request).
3rd day it request me the validation code again...

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This could be related to the expiry of a oAuth token. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by calling the API each 30 minutes instead of each day, in order to refresh the token (but I still do the real job once a day).